# Trying to create a 2 in one form and toggle hiding / showing any useful tips and tricks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to create a 2 in one form contact and offerte.
here is the problem I tried to write a code but it only works in firefox on pc, not in any other browser or device. here is what I have.
so what I wanted to create is that contact and offerte are not visible by default.
and if you click on an option that the div is visible.

```js
$("#offerte").hide();
$("#contact").hide();
$("#option1").click(function() {
  $("#offerte").hide("slow");
  $("#contact").hide("slow");
});
$("#option2").click(function() {
  $("#offerte").hide("slow");
  $("#contact").show("slow");
});
$("#option3").click(function() {
  $("#offerte").show("slow");
  $("#contact").show("slow");
});
```

```css
#form {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: form;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "algemeen" "offerte" "contact";
  background-color: #20254b;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #20254b;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.label input,
.label select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.vereist {
  color: red;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.tablelabel {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px
}

.tablelabel td {
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tablelabel input {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#algemeen {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: algemeen;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "voornaam" "naam" "telefoon" "mail" "onderwerp"
}

#voornaam {
  grid-area: voornaam;
}

#naam {
  grid-area: naam;
}

#telefoon {
  grid-area: telefoon;
}

#onderwerp {
  grid-area: onderwerp;
}

#mail {
  grid-area: mail;
}

#offerte {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: offerte;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "diensten" "event" "land" "bedrijf" "btw" "straat" "huisnummer" "gemeente" "postcode";
  line-height: 40px;
}

#gevraagde_diensten {
  grid-area: diensten;
}

#event {
  grid-area: event
}

#land {
  grid-area: land;
}

#bedrijf {
  grid-area: bedrijf;
}

#btw {
  grid-area: btw;
}

#straat {
  grid-area: straat;
}

#huisnummer {
  grid-area: huisnummer;
}

#gemeente {
  grid-area: gemeente;
}

#postcode {
  grid-area: postcode;
}

#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: none;
}

#contact input {
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="form">
  <div id="algemeen">
    <label id="voornaam" class="label">
        Voornaam
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="naam" class="label">
        Naam
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="telefoon" class="label">
        Telefoon/Mobiel
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="mail" class="label">
        E-mail
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="onderwerp" class="label">
        Onderwerp
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <select>
      <option id="option1" value="keuze">Kies een onderwerp</option>
      <option id="option2" value="contact">Ik heb een vraag.</option>
      <option id="option3" value="offerte">Vrijblijvende offerte aanvragen.</option>
    </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="offerte">
    <label id="gevraagde_diensten" class="tablelabel">
        Kies 1 of meerdere diensten
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <table width="200">
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Administratief" id="diensten_0">
                Administratief</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Fotografie" id="diensten_1">
                Fotografie</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Social Media" id="diensten_2">
                Social Media</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Budgetbeheer" id="diensten_3">
                Budgetbeheer</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Klantenservice" id="diensten_4">
                Klantenservice</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Diverse Diensten" id="diensten_5">
                Diverse Diensten</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Webdesign" id="diensten_6">
                Webdesign</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Anders" id="diensten_7">
                Anders</label></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </label>
    <label id="bedrijf" class="label">Bedrijf
          <input type="text">
        </label>
    <label id="btw" class="label">BTW-Nummer
          <input type="text">
        </label>
    <label id="straat" class="label">
        Adres
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="huisnummer" class="label">
        Huisnummer
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="gemeente" class="label">
        Gemeente
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="postcode" class="label">
        Postcode
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="contact">
    <label id="bericht" class="label">
        Bericht
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <textarea rows="15"></textarea>
    </label>
    <label id="verzend">
          <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Verzenden">
        </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're attaching the event to the click of the `option`, which is not well supported.

Instead, hook the `change` event handler to the `select` element directly. Then you can use the `value` property to determine which option was selected. From there you could use a `switch` statement to handle updating the UI based on that value.

In addition, you should set the default `display` state of hidden elements in CSS, not JS, so that you avoid a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

Here's a working example:

```js
let $offerte = $('#offerte');
let $contact = $('#contact');

$('#onderwerp select').on('change', e => {
  let value = e.target.value;
  
  switch (value) {
    case 'keuze':
      $offerte.add($contact).hide('slow');
      break;
    case 'contact':
      $offerte.hide('slow');
      $contact.show('slow');
      break;
    case 'offerte':
      $offerte.show('slow');
      $contact.hide('slow');
      break;    
  }
});
```

```css
#form {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: form;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "algemeen" "offerte" "contact";
  background-color: #20254b;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #20254b;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.label input,
.label select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.vereist {
  color: red;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.tablelabel {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px
}

.tablelabel td {
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tablelabel input {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#algemeen {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: algemeen;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "voornaam" "naam" "telefoon" "mail" "onderwerp"
}

#voornaam {
  grid-area: voornaam;
}

#naam {
  grid-area: naam;
}

#telefoon {
  grid-area: telefoon;
}

#onderwerp {
  grid-area: onderwerp;
}

#mail {
  grid-area: mail;
}

#offerte {
  display: none;
  grid-area: offerte;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "diensten" "event" "land" "bedrijf" "btw" "straat" "huisnummer" "gemeente" "postcode";
  line-height: 40px;
}

#gevraagde_diensten {
  grid-area: diensten;
}

#event {
  grid-area: event
}

#land {
  grid-area: land;
}

#bedrijf {
  grid-area: bedrijf;
}

#btw {
  grid-area: btw;
}

#straat {
  grid-area: straat;
}

#huisnummer {
  grid-area: huisnummer;
}

#gemeente {
  grid-area: gemeente;
}

#postcode {
  grid-area: postcode;
}

#contact { display: none; }
#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: none;
}

#contact input {
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="form">
  <div id="algemeen">
    <label id="voornaam" class="label">
      Voornaam
      <label class="vereist"> *</label>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="naam" class="label">
      Naam
      <label class="vereist"> *</label>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="telefoon" class="label">
      Telefoon/Mobiel
      <label class="vereist"> *</label>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="mail" class="label">
      E-mail
      <label class="vereist"> *</label>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="onderwerp" class="label">
      Onderwerp
      <label class="vereist"> *</label>
      <select>
        <option id="option1" value="keuze">Kies een onderwerp</option>
        <option id="option2" value="contact">Ik heb een vraag.</option>
        <option id="option3" value="offerte">Vrijblijvende offerte aanvragen.</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="offerte">
    <label id="gevraagde_diensten" class="tablelabel">
        Kies 1 of meerdere diensten
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <table width="200">
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Administratief" id="diensten_0">
                Administratief</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Fotografie" id="diensten_1">
                Fotografie</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Social Media" id="diensten_2">
                Social Media</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Budgetbeheer" id="diensten_3">
                Budgetbeheer</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Klantenservice" id="diensten_4">
                Klantenservice</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Diverse Diensten" id="diensten_5">
                Diverse Diensten</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Webdesign" id="diensten_6">
                Webdesign</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="diensten" value="Anders" id="diensten_7">
                Anders</label></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </label>
    <label id="bedrijf" class="label">Bedrijf
          <input type="text">
        </label>
    <label id="btw" class="label">BTW-Nummer
          <input type="text">
        </label>
    <label id="straat" class="label">
        Adres
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="huisnummer" class="label">
        Huisnummer
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="gemeente" class="label">
        Gemeente
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <input type="text">
    </label>
    <label id="postcode" class="label">
        Postcode
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="contact">
    <label id="bericht" class="label">
        Bericht
        <label class="vereist"> *</label>
    <textarea rows="15"></textarea>
    </label>
    <label id="verzend">
          <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Verzenden">
        </label>
  </div>
</form>
```